# Ajax GET passing the incorrect data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this HTML / PHP code:

```
$notes.='<div class="note '.$color.'" ';

    if($row["xyz"] == '') {
        $notes.='style="left:45%; top:10%; z-index:0;"><h3 align="center">New Note</h3>';
    } else {
        $notes.='style="left:'.$left.'px;top:'.$top.'px;z-index:'.$zindex.'">';
    }

    $notes.=htmlspecialchars($row['text']).'
    <a class="closeMessage">X</a><div class="addedby">'.htmlspecialchars($row['addedby']).'</div>
    <span class="data">'.$row['sequence'].'</span>
    </div>';
```

there are multiple containing different data from the database

i would like to use ajax to send data to a PHP page using GET, i currently have this:

```
$('.closeMessage').live('click',function(){
        //alert("close");
        alert($('span.data').html());
        $.get('/includes/sticky_notes/closeMessage.php',{
            sequence : $('span.data').html()
        });
        alert("close");
    });
```

but its passing the incorrect sequence each time. its passing the sequence number of a different row

Comment: class .data is used only 1 time in your html?

Comment: Then try to use the id tag instead of class data and do try to use $('#yourId').html() maybe it can help

Comment: if other span had class=data then it's because of that then the sequence was incorrect

Comment: Run a console.log($('span.data')) instead. Inspect the returned elements

Comment: What does not work as expected? PHP or JS?

Comment: its not passing the correct $_GET value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your HTML code for the notes have several elements with the class `'data'`, when you call for `$('span.data').html()` you will always get the inner html of the first span with the data class.

You can [traverse](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) the dom tree and use something like the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.closeMessage').on('click',function(){
      //alert("close");
      this_data = $(this).siblings('.data').html();
      alert(this_data);

      $.get('/includes/sticky_notes/closeMessage.php',{
        sequence : this_data
      });

      alert("close");
    });
});
```

In this example we store the data in a variable `this_data = $(this).siblings('.data').html()`, so we refer to the element that was clicked - `$(this)` and then go down in the tree until the next element with the class `data`.

One last thing - consider to use `$('.closeMessage').on` instead of `live` as it has been deprecated - http://api.jquery.com/live/